# iOS autocompletion not working on RxCocoa Xcode 8.3

Tags: ios, swift, rx-cocoa

I'm having problem with RxSwift and RxCocoa. I have update to latest version 3.3 and Xcode 8.3 But there are problem with autocomplete feature with RxCocoa.

Every time I write textfield.rx.text.  There will be no autocomple

```
import UIKit
import RxSwift
import RxCocoa

class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var textField2: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var textField1: UITextField!

var textField1Observerble: Driver<String?>!
var textField2Observerble: Driver<String?>!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    textField1.rx.text.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

How can we fix that?

Comment: Same issue, Xcode 8.3.3, RxSwift 3.6

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround:

You could add `asObservable()` at the end and then use dot operator to get auto complete suggestion like the following:

```
textField1.rx.text.asObservable().
```